# Captured a city, but it's completely non-functioning

Tags: civilization-4

I've just captured my first city, and it's uh... not working. The borders don't extend beyond the single tile where the city is, and I can't build anything. What do I do?

In Civ 3, you'd sometimes get a message after capturing a city informing you of a resistance, which you could quell by garrisonning military units there. Is that what's going on? I didn't get any message informing me of it.

Comment: When you capture cities they're basically in revolt for a couple turns before they settle down and start being productive, and even then you'll have some unhappiness for quite a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the comments, a city captured has to go through X turns of resistance before you can do anything with it, and its borders will remain at zero for that duration as well. There is an exception for recapturing a city that you originally owned (planted with a settler) but previously lost.

The duration is both on the map screen and the top of the city screen:
[image: Map Screen]

[image: City Screen]

The formula for duration of resistance (which cannot be reduced by any game mechanic) can be found in the source code under `...\CvGameCoreDLL\CvPlayer.cpp`:

```
pNewCity->changeOccupationTimer(((GC.getDefineINT("BASE_OCCUPATION_TURNS") + ((pNewCity->getPopulation() * GC.getDefineINT("OCCUPATION_TURNS_POPULATION_PERCENT")) / 100)) * (100 - iTeamCulturePercent)) / 100);
```

In other words, there is a flat resistance duration plus additional time for each population point modified by how much culture you have in the city. Without mods, using the constants found under `\Assets\XML\GlobalDefines.xml`, this comes out to be
**3 + [Population] * 0.5 * (100 - [Your Culture]) / 100**

So for most conquests, you will face resistance of 3 turns plus half the city size.

Comment: Can [Your Culture] be greater than 100?

Comment: No, that's your culture percentage in the city (it's in the lower left of the city screen above the production queue), and you can't see it for cities that you don't own.